# Hyperledger Fabric: Querying private data using memberOnlyRead feature

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, peer

collections_config.json file:

```
    "name": "Org1PDC",
    "policy": "OR('Org1MSP.member', 'Org2MSP.member')",
    "requiredPeerCount": 0,
    "maxPeerCount": 3,
    "blockToLive":0,
    "memberOnlyRead": false
```

I try to query data using Org3 by setting Org3's parameters in cli and executing peer chaincode query command.

But it shows that Org3 does not have permission to view the data.
I understand that CLIENTS of non-member organisations can query authorized PEERS holding private data. But I don't understand how I can achieve this functionality.